# Combining an sp object with ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, r-sp, rgdal

I have read in sp object using `geo <- readOGR`. And when I use `plot(geo)` I get the following image:

[image]

It is some data that I have downloaded from a public agency in Denmark.

How can I combine the borders of the "states" from the above plot with the plot with ggmap bellow:

```
library(ggplot)
library(maps)
library(ggmap)


ggplot() + borders(regions = "Denmark", colour = "gray50", fill = "gray50")
```

What I would like to a achieve is a plot where each polygon has a color on a color scale based on some calculation.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question but convert `geo` to a `sf` object and use `geom_sf` : `library(sf); geo_sf <- st_as_sf(geo); ggplot() + geom_sf(data = geo_sf)` A good read : https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/adv-map.html#other-mapping-packages

Comment: @ markus: thanks for the link. But why not just read in the data as an sf object. I thought the sp object was *the* object for geospatial objects i r.

Comment: Reading in as `sf` object is surely the better option. I think `sf` became the standard object class but I just got started with geocomputation a couple of weeks back - so I might be wrong about it.